# Specifying proxies for http vs https sites when using Python Requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a Python script to get a page using Requests. I need to use proxies to access the page. When I access an http page, it goes through the proxy but when I access an https page, it does not go through the proxy (I used logs to check this, as explained below). I have checked with the proxy service provider (proxymesh) and they said that their proxies can be used for https pages as well. Is there anything I need to change in the script when accessing https sites vs http sites?

My code is presented below. At the end of this question, I have included the log files generated for the http and https sites, which show that the proxy is used for http but not for https.

Any ideas will be really helpful.

```
import logging
import requests

#set up logging
logging.getLogger('').handlers = []

logging.basicConfig(
filename = "mylog_with_proxy.log", #in my code, the full path is specified
filemode="w",
level = logging.DEBUG)

#specify proxies and headers
proxies = {'http': 'http://fr.proxymesh.com:31280', 'https': 'http://fr.proxymesh.com:31280'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393',}

#the two URLs that I accessed. One is for an http site and the other one is for an https site. These sites are just examples of sites I need to access.
http_url = "http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/"
https_url = "https://www.haskell.org/happy/"

#get the page. I executed the script twice - once for http_url and the second time for https_url. Here, it shows http_url
r = requests.get(http_url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=5)
r.raise_for_status()
```

The log files are as shown below:

When accessing the http site (that is, when running the script with http_url):

> INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): fr.proxymesh.com
>
> DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 None

When accessing the https site (that is, when running the script with https_url)

> INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.haskell.org
>
> DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /happy/ HTTP/1.1" 200 None

Comment: Why do you need to use a proxy to access an https page? The https means the page is secure in the first place.

Comment: I am trying to automate some data collection, and need to access the sites using proxies for this.